# Why do I get different SpamAssassin results via spamd vs command line

Tags: spamassassin

My SpamAssassin daemon is not flagging as much spam as I would like (but it *is* flagging *some*), so I took a sample message which had not been flagged, and ran it thru SpamAssassin at the command line. The results are entirely different for the *same message* (see below).

- What should I look for in the configuration which might cause this?
- How can I temporarily enable debug for spamd (Ubuntu 16.4, not using amavis)

Results via spamd:

```
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.0 (2014-02-07) on myhost
X-Spam-Level:
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-1.1 required=2.0 tests=BAYES_00,RDNS_NONE,
    SPF_HELO_PASS,URIBL_BLOCKED autolearn=no autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
```

Results via command line:

```
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.0 (2014-02-07) on myhost
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Level: ****
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=4.5 required=2.0 tests=RCVD_IN_BL_SPAMCOP_NET,
    RDNS_NONE,SPF_HELO_PASS,SPF_PASS,URIBL_ABUSE_SURBL,URIBL_BLOCKED autolearn=no
    autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
X-Spam-Report: 
  *  0.0 URIBL_BLOCKED ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to URIBL was blocked.
  *       See http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists#dnsbl-block
  *      for more information.
  *      [URIs: sarasotasailingsquadron.org]
  *  1.9 URIBL_ABUSE_SURBL Contains an URL listed in the ABUSE SURBL
  *      blocklist
  *      [URIs: afxled.trade]
*  1.2 RCVD_IN_BL_SPAMCOP_NET RBL: Received via a relay in bl.spamcop.net
*      [Blocked - see <http://www.spamcop.net/bl.shtml?107.173.40.66>]
* -0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF record
* -0.0 SPF_HELO_PASS SPF: HELO matches SPF record
*  1.3 RDNS_NONE Delivered to internal network by a host with no rDNS
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the actual configuration it's hard to say what could be wrong. This might be some permission issue, for example if the spamd is running as a user that doesn't have permissions to read `~/.spamassassin/user_prefs` and, therefore, only runs the tests and scores configured in `/etc/spamassassin/local.cf`.

> How can I temporarily enable debug for spamd?

Run it with `spamd -D` (i.e. `--debug` for printing debugging messages). You can compare the output to the output of `spamassassin -D` to see what's the difference.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, first check spamd status with

```
sudo systemctl status spamassassin
```

It might give you a clue. For example file permission issue:

```
spamd[2392]: bayes: cannot open bayes databases /var/lib/spamassassin/.spamassassin/bayes_* R/O: tie failed: Permission denied
```

The file should be owned by spamd user. In my case `debian-spamd`, but can be owned by root if you ran `sa-learn` with sudo.